# Change status in status bar

Tags: python, scripting

I want to use `bpy.context.workspace.status_text_set(text="HelloWorld")`

The problem is it is working just in draw, modal, execute methods of my operators, but I want to change it from class which not inherited from `bpy.types.Operator`
in this class `bpy.context.workspace` is `None`

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved with global variable and function which registered as blender timer.

```
status = {'prev': None, 'new': None}


def set_status(text):
    try:
        status.update({'prev': status['new'],
                       'new': text})
    except:
        pass


def status_timer():
    try:
        if status['new'] != status['prev']:
            bpy.context.workspace.status_text_set(text=status['new'])
        return 1
    except Exception as e:
        return None
```

and add to register() function
`bpy.app.timers.register(status_timer)`

Comment: Great you solved it, but more details please.

Comment: Is this missing a call to `set_status`?

Comment: you can call `set_status` everywhere you want text: text for status, type=string